# Images cut off at the end

Tags: css

The images on the right hand side of my website are cut off. I'm using a theme (I didn't design it) that is based on the 960 grid. I played around with it to make the images big and overlap but in doing that I made the images on the right hand side cut off.

Here is the [site](http://basement001.tumblr.com)

I tried changing the grid width *(I increased the width on grid 3 and grid 12)* but nothing happened, the images still stayed cut off (only on the right side though).

I used firebug and it showed that the grid has more than enough room for the images to scoot over. I don't know why they haven't.

This is the css

```
/* Standard 960px ----------- */

.grid_1                             { width:48px; }
.grid_2                             { width:128px; }
.grid_3                             { width:260px; }
.grid_4                             { width:960px; }
.grid_5                             { width:368px; }        
.grid_6                             { width:448px; }
.grid_7                             { width:528px; }
.grid_8                             { width:960px; }
.grid_9                             { width:688px; }
.grid_10                            { width:768px; }
.grid_11                            { width:848px; }
.grid_12                            { width:1100px; }

.column                             { margin:0 0px 0 0px; overflow:hidden; float:left; display:inline; }
.row                                { margin:0 auto; width:960px; overflow:hidden; }
.row .row                           { margin:0 -10px 0 -10px; width:auto; display:inline-block; }
```

Comment: how about `overflow: visible`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS is a little bit strange... but to see full photos just remove overflow:hidden from ".row".

I don't know what You trying to do, but it's not good idea to use DIV to make something like TABLE (.row, .column).

Comment: I'm new to css :-/ Thank you, I will try removing the overflow

Comment: Thank you for your help, it worked. I'm going to look into the divs now and change them (i didn't make the theme). Have a good day :)